# Create a C function that accepts parameters of different data types

Tags: c, function

I'm relatively new to the C programming language, and I'm trying to figure out how to create a function that can accept different types of data as parameters. The function is supposed to count and return the number of elements in a character or integer array. I already have two separate functions that will do this, but I would really like to be able to use one function for both tasks. Is there a way to do this in C?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no standard function overloading in C (nor are there templates), but you could probably look into "printf-like" functions (or [variadic functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function)) and maybe they can do what you need. If anything they allow for a flexible parameter list.

There is an example [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Variadic-Example.html) of such a function that takes a variable size integer array.

Perhaps you could have a function signature such as `void iterate(const char* format, ...);` that you use in the following ways:

```
iterate("char", some_char_array); // for char arrays/strings
```

Or

```
iterate("int", some_int_array); // for integer arrays
```

Aniket makes a good point though, how do you count the elements in an integer array? If you pass an int array as an argument, you would need to pass the size too which defeats the purpose of counting the elements in the array (as you already know that i.e. the size).

I assume you don't know the size but you have a terminator value in the array (such as -1).

I've hacked something quick that kinda does what you need with the above assumption in mind.

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
 
int iterate(const char* format, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, format);

    if (strcmp(format, "char") == 0)
    {
        char* array = va_arg(ap, char*);

        va_end(ap);
        return strlen(array);
    }
    else if (strcmp(format, "int") == 0)
    {
        int j = -1;
        int* int_array = va_arg(ap, int*);
        while (int_array[++j] != -1)
                    ;   
        va_end(ap);  
        return j;
    }
    va_end(ap);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", iterate("char", "abcdef"));
    int arr[] = {5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1};
    printf("%d\n", iterate("int", arr));

    return 0;
}
```

This prints:

```
$ ./a.out 
6
6
```

Comment: Size of the array? I'll clarify this as it appears not to be clear.

Comment: well if he knows the size of array before hand, why will he use a super function like this to automatically infer the type and call the appropriate function to compute the length of the array? :-)

Comment: I thought the idea is to have one function that does that? :) Of course the above is just a suggestion, I'm not sure how OP uses the functions to count the elements in an array. If OP follows the example on the GNU website then I guess there won't be a need to pass the size. If OP just passes an array as an argument, at least in the case of an integer array there would need to be a way to terminate the iteration.

Comment: I've removed the `int size` from the function signature, it's only necessary in the case of an integer array and then it can be part of the variadic arguments.

Comment: @Nobilis Thanks! Just from the information that you gave about variadic functions, I was able to figure it out and create one function to accept both character and integer arrays.

Comment: I know is Old, but the CODE showed has a conversion problem which the Author did not noticed it. Inside the `int iterate(const char* format, ...)` function,  there is the return statement `return strlen(array);` which is obvious `long unsigned int` but the function returns `int`. This is a bad cod/Answer. It does not follow the `C` standard at all.

Answer (score 5):

So, let's assume your two functions are called `sizeof_char_array` and `sizeof_int_array`.

In C11, there is a new feature called "generic selection" that will let you do what you want with a relatively simple macro:

```
#define sizeof_array(X) \
    _Generic (*(X), \
              char: sizeof_char_array, \
              default: sizeof_int_array) (X)
```

(I don't even have a C11 implementation to test this against, so caveat emptor!)

Prior to C11, this was sometimes accomplished with a macro using regularly named functions. You can define a macro that will call one function or the other depending on a macro argument hint:

```
#define sizeof_array(xtype, x) sizeof_ ## xtype ##_array(x)

int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, -1 };
char b[] = "abc";

sizeof_array(int, a);   /* macro expands to sizeof_int_array(a) */
sizeof_array(char, b);  /* macro expands to sizeof_char_array(b) */
```

If the input argument is truly an array, you can use a macro to compute its size directly:

```
#define ARRAY_SZ(x) (sizeof(x)/((void *)x == &x ? sizeof(x[0]) : 0))
```

In the case of an array, the following expression is true:

```
(void *)arr == &arr
```

Because the address of an array has the same location in memory as the address of its first element.

So, the macro computes: `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])`. Since the `sizeof` operator reports the size in bytes of its argument, the computed expression results in the number of elements in the array. However, if you are using a sentinel to compute the length, the `ARRAY_SZ` macro will result in a size at least one larger than the length found traversing the array for the sentinel.

In the case that the argument is not an array, then the expression results in a divide by 0 exception.

Comment: strictly speaking :-P, the OP wants to call two different functions from one function depending upon the type of data the pointer holds.

Comment: So I guess, he wants some sort of type-inferencing system. Just my thought on this.

Comment: @Aniket: That doesn't make much sense to me, since you cannot infer the length of an array after it is passed to a function. The length of the array needs to be passed to the function (unless the inference is done through a sentinel value).

Comment: precisely my point. He has two functions to call, one for each type to compute the length of the array. He wants to call one or the other depending on the type of array passed to the function.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is quite simple. You do need a function for this task. Just try this piece of code

```
#define len(array) sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array)
```

and that's it.

**Important note**: As pointed out in the comments, this will not work for dynamically allocated arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You should make your function arguments take in a `void *` type.  This way, you can pass in different types of data, and type-cast it to the one you want.  However, you do need to watch out because there is no guaranteed way to correctly 'guess' the type that a `void*` points to.

Answer (score 2):

In either case, you will need some sort of type-inferencing system to tell the C compiler which function to call. Which means, you will need to know, before-hand the type of array you might send in as a parameter to this "super function" of yours.

There is no "auto-type-inferencing" in C that can let you reflect upon the type of data at runtime. Better yet, you might have to write your own runtime environment for this to happen.

A slightly trivial hackish way to do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t GetLengthOfArray(size_t sizeOfOneElementInArray, size_t sizeOfTheArrayInBytes)
{
   return sizeOfTheArrayInBytes/sizeOfOneElementInArray; 
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   char cArr[10] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J'};
   int iArr[5] = {10,20,30,40,50};
   printf("%d is the length of cArr\n%d is the length of iArr",GetLengthOfArray(sizeof(cArr[0]),sizeof(cArr)),
                                                               GetLengthOfArray(sizeof(iArr[0]),sizeof(iArr)));
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not really possible, but you can make a [tagged union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union)

```
typedef struct {
    union {
        ssize_t i;
        double d;
        char *s;
    } unknown;
    char identity;
} Dynamic;
```

Or you can use a void pointer:

```
typedef struct {
  void *unknown;
  char identity;
} Dynamic;
```