# Passing arguments of any type to function in C

Tags: c

I would like to ask if it is possible to use a "void" variable that works the same as the pointer void (where you can store a pointer to any type of data like `int`, `char` etc). For example, `function(void variable)` to which I can pass any variable, like `function(4)` or `function("hi")`.
Thank you!
PD: I'm doing an exercise related to simple linked lists (through structs)

```c
typedef struct _GNodo {
    void *dato;struct _GNodo *sig;
} GNodo;

GList GList_agregar_final(GList lista, void dato) {
  GNodo *nuevoNodo = malloc(sizeof(GNodo));
  nuevoNodo->dato = dato;
  nuevoNodo->sig = NULL;

  if (lista == NULL)
    return nuevoNodo;

  GList nodo = lista;
  for (;nodo->sig != NULL;nodo = nodo->sig);
  /* ahora 'nodo' apunta al ultimo elemento en la lista */

  nodo->sig = nuevoNodo;
  return lista;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17667189/11683, but it doesn't look from your code that you [actually want](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147640) that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a C function that accepts parameters of different data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667189/create-a-c-function-that-accepts-parameters-of-different-data-types)

Answer (score 2):

No, the compiler needs to know the size of a parameter. It works with a pointer since `void *` has a known size, but `void` does not.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in standard C. Read e.g. [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) or some newer standard. Since some implementations passes argument in CPU registers (a different register for `int` and `double`, for example [Linux amd64 ABI](https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/elf/x86_64-abi-0.99.pdf))
.

See also [variadic functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic) with `<stdarg.h>` which requires at least one fixed argument

You could also pass a pointer to some `union`, or a `union` of pointers and other types. Of course, you need a *documented* convention to choose the `union` member. Read more about [tagged unions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union). Study for inspiration the source code of [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) or of the [sash shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-alone_shell). They are [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_software) software.

BTW `GList` could be used in [GTK](https://gtk.org/) (its [Glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/) part). Study it carefully, it is a well written open source toolkit: download its source code and study it. It has some [`GVariant`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-GVariant.html)

Consider also using the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/), or [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/), or even [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) (a static analyzer above [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) for embedded code written in C or C++) on your C source code. For Frama-C or Bismon contact me by email to `basile.starynkevitch@cea.fr`

If you use [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) to compile your C code, [invoke it](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger to understand the behavior of your program.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can׳t because the compiler must know the argument size at compilation time, if you want to pass a generic object you should pass void * instead, this is fine because the size of a pointer is known at compilation time.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can:

```
List GList_agregar_final(GList lista, const void *dato, size_t dataSize) {
  GNodo *nuevoNodo = malloc(sizeof(*nuevoNodo));
  /* check if allocation did not fail */
  nuevoNodo->dato = malloc(dataSize);
  /* check if allocation did not fail */
  memcpy(nuevoNodo -> dato, data, dataSize);
  nuevoNodo->sig = NULL;
  /* ... */
```

```
    GList_agregar_final(lista, (int[]){4}, sizeof((int[]){4}));
    GList_agregar_final(lista, "hi", sizeof("hi"));
```

Do not use types in the sizeof only objects as in my example